# site launches from webmatrix ok, but visual studio shows dir listing

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webmatrix

I'm developping site in webmatrix. I was having some trouble with my variables and database insert so decided to try debugging using visual studio (from the webmatrix launch button).

When I run the site from visual studio it just shows me the directory listing.
the URL is: http://localhost:50051/learning/

When I run the same page from webmatrix it is fine.
The URL is: http://localhost:31430/Default.cshtml

I can see that the localhost number is different and that the visual studio one is not pointing to the default page but just the the root folder. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution...right mouse click on the web site project in Visual Studio and click on use IIS Express and run again.